# Ember.js: bind query param to select menu whose content is loaded asynchronously

Tags: ember.js

I have a user search form with a country filter. The countries in the select menu (drop down) are loaded asynchronously with ember-data. The selected country is bound to a query param:

`https://myapp.com/users?country=123`

- **Working**: when the user selects a country from the select menu, the URL is updated and contains the country id
- **Not working**: when the user browses back to a URL containing a country as query parameter, the select menu does contain all the countries **but**  is not selecting the right country + the query param becomes undefined: `/users?country=undefined`

Template:

```
{{view "select" 
        content=countries 
        value=country
        optionLabelPath="content.name"
        optionValuePath="content.id"}}
```

Controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    countries: Ember.computed(function () {
        return this.store.find('country');
    }),

    country: null,

    queryParams: ['country'],

});
```

Route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.find('user', params);
    }
});
```

Any suggestions? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

I was so close! It appeared that I was loading the countries too late, therefore the select had no data to match with the query parameter.

I just moved the code loading the countries in the `model` hook:

```
model: function (params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        users: this.store.find('user', params),
        // Pre-load the countries so the queryParams binding
        // with the select menu work properly
        countries: this.store.find('countries')
    });
},
```

It seems obvious now that I have found the solution!